# sqlite3: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

Error: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied.

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('collyers_car_park.db')

cursor = connection.cursor()

# create details table
details_table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
details(
user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
)"""

details_default_values = [
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5)
]

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO details (user_id) VALUES (?)", [details_default_values])
connection.commit()

latest_id = cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM details WHERE user_id = (SELECT MAX(user_id)) FROM details""")
print(latest_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied.` is thrown because details_default_values is already a list, and you are wrapping inside another list in the row `cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO details (user_id) VALUES (?)", [details_default_values])` causing the first insert to contain 5 values instead of 1.

However, another following error: Since the code uses single value tuples you would need to put each tuple with a comma inside like this `(1,)`

The below code is almost same as your and runs. Please note that i adjusted some other parts in the code since it wouldn't run, so other parts are slightly different from your code. Posted my adjustments to supply an example that runs successfully :)

```py
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('collyers_car_park.db')

cursor = connection.cursor()

# create details table
details_table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
details(
user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);"""
cursor.execute(details_table)
details_default_values = [(1,),(2,),(3,),(4,),(5,)] # <---- single value tuples

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO details (user_id) VALUES (?)", details_default_values)
connection.commit()

latest_id = cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM details""")
print(latest_id.fetchall())
```

Comment: Thank you - I am now getting the error `sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: details.user_id`

Comment: Yes, that is because you try to insert the same values over and over again. If you want to re-run with the same inserted values you would need to drop the table and re-create it. Add `cursor.execute("DROP TABLE details;")` before creating the table and you can re run the code again.

Comment: @BenjaminMcDowell see above comment. Hope it helped, and please accept answer if you found it helpful :) Thanks!

Comment: oops sorry, that was a stupid question from me - thank you. Why did you shorten the SELECT command, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I just created a quick example that would run :) that select statement was throwing a syntax error as well but i ignored that and focused on the question at hand