# How to turn an interger list to single value tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I wrote a code to delete some users from the database, but it said `Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied`.

```
def delete_user(self, user_id):
    stmt = "DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id = (?)"
    args = user_id
    try:
        self.conn.executemany(stmt, (args,))
        self.conn.commit()
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        logging.error(str(e))
```

My part main code:

```
    deleted_user = []
    deleted_user.append(1384995383)
    deleted_user.append(1667596031)
    deleted_user.append(1332658866)
    deleted_user.append(1295962235)

    print(deleted_user)
    db.delete_user(deleted_user)
```

I found this answer: [sqlite3: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66412636/sqlite3-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-statement-uses-1-an)

I try to use `tuple(user_id)` to convert it to a tuple, but the result was not I'm except

Origin deleted_user list:

```
[1384995383, 1667596031, 1332658866, 1295962235]
```

After tuple(user_id) result:

```
(1384995383, 1667596031, 1332658866, 1295962235)
```

What I Expectation:

```
[(1384995383,), (1667596031,), (1332658866,), (1295962235,)]
```

I tried searching, but I couldn't get the answers I wanted :(

Comment: A tuple only containing "item" is written as "(item,)". The comma is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def delete_user_ids(self, user_ids):
    stmt = "DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id = (?)"
    try:
        self.conn.executemany(stmt, user_ids)
#                                   ^^^^^^^^
```

```py
user_ids = []
user_ids.append((1384995383,))
user_ids.append((1667596031,))
user_ids.append((1332658866,))
user_ids.append((1295962235,))
delete_user_ids(user_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
deleted_user.append((1384995383,))
```